# Need to enter a dhclient at every restart at Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

my internet was working just fine until one certain day. From this day until today every time I restart the pc I have to execute a dhclient to make internet connection work again.
I searched old threads and found this: [Have to dhclient each restart to access internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/248876/have-to-dhclient-each-restart-to-access-internet)
Unfortunatelly none of the proposed solutions worked for me. Here my /etc/network/interface it is:

> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback

I changed the two lo to eth0 and didn't work. Then I looked at the /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases and there exists a line

> interface "eth0"

so following the link tip, changing the internet interface of /etc/network/interface to the same value of /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases should work, but it didn't for me.
Also putting dhclient at the /etc/rc.local didn't work.

So, any tips?

---

Sorry to open this question. The mistake was mine, the last line was

> iface lo inet loopback

and I changed it to

> iface eth0 inet loopback

instead of changing it to

> iface eth0 inet dhcp

Anyway, how was possible that this file was changed (I am assuming that before it was

> iface eth0 inet dhcp

to this loopback interface? What could possible happen to provoke that?

Answer (score 4):

You should not change the entries in `/etc/network/interfaces` that refer to the `lo` interface.

Your entries for `eth0` should look like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

For a detailed howto see:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/

Also this question on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/151936/how-to-automate-running-the-dhclient-in-ubuntu

Comment: There was nothing in the interfaces file besides "auto lo
iface lo inet loopback"

Comment: Yep that's the default entry when you have no network at all. The eth0 lines needed to be added.

Comment: Thank you! I have a very vanilla installation of xubuntu which I two days ago upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 to 18.04 The upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 somehow replaced the `/etc/network/interfaces` file with the default and thus dhcp stopped working. I could connect and ping IP-addresses but no name servers were being configured. Adding the entries for `eth0` as you said above fixed the problem completely. Thank you!! :-)